# System Internals procexp64 wont restore Task Manager

Tags: windows, sysinternals

Prior versions of Process Explorer would allow you to toggle on/off the Replace with Task Manager option.  However the current version seems not to toggle so well.  After turning it on I can no longer turn it off.  In this screenshot there is not check next the option even though it actually is active. Whenever I attempt to access the Windows Task Manager Process Explorer shows up uninvitedly.

I have attempted to rename the procexp64.exe in hopes that it would not find itself and restore Task Manager but that failed.

How can I get it to turn off?

Comment: You need to ask the author of that software, or file a bug report with them.

Comment: What screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

To replace Task Manager with Process Explorer, the `Image File Execution Options` registry key is used.  The key can be found here:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`

In this case Process Explorer creates the sub key `taskmgr.exe` and sets the `Debugger` `REG_SZ` value to be the path of Process Explorer wherever you have it on disk.

To remove this behaviour you can simply launch `Regedit.exe` and delete the key:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe` or leave the key and delete the `Debugger` named value under the above key.